# Where's the response data from a 500 error in NSURLSession?

Tags: nsurlsession, nshttpurlresponse

I have the following Swift code in my iOS app:

```swift
session?.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        var dataString:String?
        if data != nil {
            // Print the response as a string
            dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            if RequestManager.verbose { print("Response data: \(dataString)") }
        } else {
            if RequestManager.verbose { print("Response data: \(response?.description)") }
        }
        //[...]
```

When the calls to the web-service API succeed this works fine: `response!.statusCode` is set correctly and the `data` passed into the completion handler can be parsed into useful objects from JSON.

However when the server response is an error, e.g. 500, then `data` is zero bytes and all I can see is the header information, not the body of the response.

Here's an example response, gleaned from the simulator using the proxy application [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/):

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=00000000000000000000888888888888888888888888aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;Path=/;Domain=blah-testing.azurewebsites.net
>   Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 05:57:44 GMT
>
> {"ExceptionType":"Exception","Message":"Not on your Nelly","StackTrace":"   at Blah.Controllers.CustomersController.Get() in D:\Users\timregan\Source\Repos\ServerSideCode\Blah\ApiControllers\CustomersController.cs:line 37\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__28.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Blah.Startup.<>c.<b__6_0>d.MoveNext() in D:\Users\timregan\Source\Repos\ServerSideCode\Blah\Startup.cs:line 59","StatusCode":500}

But in Xcode the same response has far less. The header elements are all there in the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object but the other parameters to the [`dataTaskWithRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:) completion handler have nothing: `data` is zero bytes and `error` is `nil`. Where has the body of the response with the server error stack trace in it gone? How do I access that in Swift?

Comment: It would be useful to know why my question has been down-voted, I don't think I have fallen into any obvious pitfalls? Perhaps the iOS tag is too general, I'll take that back out.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, by default, NSURLSession stops requesting data after it gets a non-200 header, so that it doesn't waste time downloading body data that you probably don't need.

If you want to actually retrieve the body data every time:

- Implement the `URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:` delegate method and make it always return `NSURLSessionResponseAllow`.
- Implement the `URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:` method and make its completion handler always pass `NULL` as the new request so that redirects won't be followed.

I *think* that should be sufficient, unless I'm forgetting another delegate method somewhere.

Comment: I've added implementations for those but they do not get called so there's no detectable difference.

Comment: Ah, right.  You also have to remove the completion handler when you create the request, and handle the data yourself with delegate methods.  Using a completion handler with a request prevents the didReceiveResponse: delegate method from ever getting called.  And I'm still not 100% certain that this will solve the problem.

Comment: calling the completionHandler with `NSURLSessionResponseAllow` (aka `.allow`) will cause `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)` to be called, where the actual data can be received and further processed.